# Как создать собственный шаблон в Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Изучил книгу "Android. Программирование для профессионалов", 2-е издание.
Там во всех проектах используются 2 файла `SingleFragmentActivity`:

```
public abstract class SingleFragmentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

protected abstract Fragment createFragment();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);

    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = createFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                .commit();
    }
}

}
```

activity_fragment:

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Как настроить AndroidStudio, чтобы при создании проекта были именно эти файлы, можно ли создать свой шаблон или другие варианты?

Помимо этих файлов еще должен быть один файл основной MainActivity, который создается при создании проекта по стандарту.

Comment: Возможно, вместо создания целого собственного шаблона проекта (что довольно муторно),  вам будет достаточно встроенного инструмента Android Studio - File and Code Templates, который позволяет сделать шаблон какого то отдельного файла (класса) и загружать его целиком. [Инструкция.](https://riggaroo.co.za/custom-file-templates-android-studio/)  То есть, чтобы получить весь класс нужно нажать на одну кнопку.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> В исходниках SDK есть описание способа решить поставленную задачу. [Android IDE Template Format.](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/refs/heads/master/templates/docs/index.html)

Для создания шаблонов используется FreeMarker. Это очень похоже на использование шаблонов PHP и Django.

Суть заключается в том, что у нас есть определенный шаблон и форма для ввода параметров. После ввода, параметры передаются в шаблон, и на основе этих данных собирается необходимый класс.

Список всех используемых шаблонов находится по следующему адресу 
android-studio-folder\plugins\android\lib\templates\

Для создания своего шаблона добавляем в директорию activities(или other) новый каталог со следующим списком файлов[image: Список файлов]

Обязательными являются только файлы template.xml и recipe.xml.

Подробнее:  [статья на хабря](https://habrahabr.ru/post/274959/).